# Change Add/Remove Program name for ClickOnce app?

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application that has the Publisher, Suite and Program names set properly through the Publish Options dialog. For example: Publisher = Microsoft, Suite = Office, Program = Word.

I want the entry in Add/Remove Program to be more than the Program name. I'd like it to contain a prefix so all programs from my suite or publisher are grouped together. So instead of having "Word" in Add/Remove Programs, I'd have "Microsoft Office Word". The only way I found to change that is to change the Program Name to Microsoft Office Word, but then that spreads to the Start menu entry and the desktop icons.

Is there a way to customize the name of a ClickOnce application in Add/Remove Programs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any proper way to do this. You can change the name in the Add/Remove programs list by changing the

*DisplayName* key in *HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[ProductCode]*

However OneClick Deyployment doesn't support any custom actions. You might eventually be better of with a reguler setup project.

I hope you can get something useful out of this..